# Ubuntu 16.04 not allowing dns queries from local reverse proxy

Tags: 16.04, dns, reverse-proxy

So I know this is not ideal but I have it set up so that all my queries to my external facing services go to the internet then back to local since I have not yet configured the proper DNS records here.

If I access the sites from any other machine on my network it is fine but my Ubuntu desktop install seems to be blocking these queries for an unknown reason. I was hoping someone might have some ideas on what I can try. I have spent about 3 hours now googling with nothing to show for it other than I tested and the queries are not even making it to my DNS server(s).

Comment: Could you post a copy of your `traceroute` output or something to give us a better idea of what the problem is?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann My install does not have that package. I ended up switching my DNS server manually to a external one instead of my internal pihole one. No the pihole was not blocking my requests.